# Getting libraries to load with newer jQuery using jqmulti

Tags: javascript

I'm kind of a newbie to this so I could be missing something really obvious, but I'm having trouble getting specific libraries to load with jQuery 1.7 in noconflict mode using jqmulti. I'm working on a theme based off twitter_bootstrap, and the bootstrap.js library is dependent on more recent jQuery. I've got jqmulti recognizing and loading 1.7 if I check "load even if no libraries are assigned" but when I have that unchecked and attempt to use hook_jqmulti_files() to assign particular libraries, nothing happens.

This is what I have in my template.php:

```
function regent_jqmulti_files() {
    return array(
        'sites/all/themes/regent/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.js',
        'sites/all/themes/regent/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js'
    );
}
```

but when I look at my rendered html, the library is loaded, but nothing about noconflict mode,  and jQ 1.7 is nowhere to be found. I'm sure I'm missing something basic and stupid, this being the first time I've tried to set something like this up.

Answer (score 1):

If you have checked "load even if no libraries are assigned", jQuery 1.7 should load regardless of anything else you do. So in your HTML you should see Drupal's jQuery loading, and you should also see jQuery1.7 loading, and also a script called `switch.js`, which takes care of the `noConflict()` mode. If you don't see those loading, there is a problem that's not related to your hook. Check the jQuery Multi settings page, does it list the jQuery version it's using?

Answer (score 0):

As you are talking of a template.php file, I get you are talking of theme code. The only hooks a theme can implement are alter hooks (the ones called with `drupal_alter()` and with a name ending in `_alter`), in Drupal 7. (Theme functions are not hooks.)

If you look at the code of [drupal_alter()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!module.inc/function/drupal_alter/7), you will notice it contains the following lines.

```
// Allow the theme to alter variables after the theme system has been
// initialized.
global $theme, $base_theme_info;
if (isset($theme)) {
  $theme_keys = array();
  foreach ($base_theme_info as $base) {
    $theme_keys[] = $base->name;
  }
  $theme_keys[] = $theme;
  foreach ($theme_keys as $theme_key) {
    $function = $theme_key . '_' . $hook;
    if (function_exists($function)) {
      $functions[$cid][] = $function;
    }
    if (isset($extra_types)) {
      foreach ($extra_types as $extra_type) {
        $function = $theme_key . '_' . $extra_type . '_alter';
        if (function_exists($function)) {
          $functions[$cid][] = $function;
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Differently, [module_implements()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!module.inc/function/module_implements/7) (used from any function that invokes hooks) doesn't check hooks implemented by themes.